# FabricJS mouse:down and drag are creating conflicts with each other

Tags: canvas, drag-and-drop, fabricjs

I am using FabricJS to render text contents. I have multiple textblocks on canvas. For all those blocks I am creating a group on mouse:down. but then I need to click outside first to drag that text group.

How to do drag while I am doing mouse:down?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution from github issues of fabricjs.js: add this line before canvas.renderAll():

```
canvas._setupCurrentTransform(event.e, sel);
```